# Copy line numbers from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, sql-management-studio

In SQL Server Management Studio, I've configured the Text Editor to show the line numbers, like so:

[image]

I want to move these into a word document for documentation. Right now if I were to highlight this piece of code, copy it, and paste it into word, I get this:

[image]

Is there an easy way for me to copy the contents, and preserve the line numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But, you could put the content into a spreadsheet, have the first column enumerate the line numbers, and then paste this in your document.

The line numbers are not part of your content, they are part of the editor visualization features.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is an excellent program for doing this, however you may need to change the settings in order to show the line numbers.